# Time complexity of append operation in simple array

Tags: arrays, computer-science, time-complexity

In the worst case while appending an element(inserting at end) array can be full. So a new array is created and **n** elements are copied from this array to the new array.

I read in literature that worst case time complexity of this operation is **O(1)**, why so? shouldn't it be **O(n)?**

I did read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235290/complexity-of-array-operations). But did not make any sense to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operation itself is O(n).

If you get the average operations *per element*, you get O(1), this is the **amortized** cost.

See more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis

Comment: I think this is the line at the heart: "The basic idea is that a worst case operation can alter the state in such a way that the worst case cannot occur again for a long time, thus "amortizing" its cost."

Comment: that's why exponential growth is used when resizing.

Comment: Are you telling that when I will create new array it would exponentially larger than previous one? If so how to choose exponent values?

Comment: Is there any such rules? Can you point to some literature please?

Comment: first hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100311/what-is-the-ideal-growth-rate-for-a-dynamically-allocated-array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48961/discussion-between-eddij-and-karoly-horvath)

Answer (score 0):

I see it the same way that you do.

If it was a List, then it was O(1) to add an element at the end.

But in the case of an array, if it´s full you need to create a new one, copy all the elements in the old array, and then add the new element.

For me it´s O(n) too.

Answer (score 0):

In case of static list/array the time complexity must be O(n), but in case of dynamic array/list, the time complexity comes O(1) because in dynamic array there is a facility to allocate extra memory for the append operation .